# What happens to cycle loop nested in openmp do loop?

Tags: loops, fortran, openmp, cycle

I have a fortran code that has nested loops. The outer loop uses openmp. The inner loop has a cycle command. I want to know for openmp, is there special treatment for the cycle in inner loop?

```
!$OMP PARALLEL
!$OMP DO schedule(static)
do i=1,N
...
loop1: do j=1,M
if() cycle loop1
enddo
enddo
!$OMP END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `cycle` in `loop1`. That loop will be executed by each thread independently and the conditional jumps within the context of each thread do not pose any problem.

Just don't forget to make `j` private! Only `i` will be made private automatically.

By the way, OpenMP allows use of `cycle` even for the `parallel do`; the [document](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf) states that

> Only an iteration of the innermost associated loop may be curtailed by a CYCLE statement.

So in your case you could use `cycle` even in the outer loop, which is your only loop *associated with* the parallel section (i.e., there aren't several `collapse`-d loops).

Comment: As far as I know and as far as we established at this site previously, both `i` and `j` will implicitly `private` if the loops are closely nested. But if the `...` contains some statements, `j` will possibly not be.

Comment: @VladimirF Your comment is very interesting. Could you please cross-link "previously" to the relevant page?